# How to use regular (cabled) speakers by wireless?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

I have regular, wired speakers and I use them for the computer. How can I use them wirelessly, by Bluetooth or Wi-Fi, from a smartphone or tablet?

I guess I need a Bluetooth device that connects to the speakers and gets power from a regular USB charger or from a powered USB hub.

Can anyone help me to find such a device on Amazon? I prefer something cheap, under $20 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KY684PB) is what you are looking for.  I have a device very similar to this one and it works great.  I’ve used it in the same situation as the one you described.

Comment: Thanks, I just got one, it is cheap, looks good and it is doing the job! It says AAC codec might not work well and that it uses SBC codec by default, but works very well anyways.